# What is this sequence counting?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, integer-sequences

While solving (a system of) a system of linear equations level-by-level recursively, I am finding some redundant equations for level $n\geq5$. The reason why the redundancies arise is because $P(n)\neq P(n-1)+P(n-2)$ for $n\geq5$. The redundancies are given by the sequence :
$$
0,0,0,0,1,1,3,4,7,10,16,21,32,43,60,80,110,\dots~.
$$

Here, $P(n)$ is the number of partitions of the integer $n$. This is the sequence is given by $P(n-1)+P(n-2)-P(n)$                     for $n\geq1$.

A generating function for the above sequence is 
$$
1 - (1-q-q^2)\prod_{n=1}^\infty {1\over (1-q^n)}~.
$$

Is this sequence (or any closely related one) encountered in some context in combinatorics? What is being counted?

(I have searched this in OEIS; there are a few sequences matching till the $16$ above but disagrees thereafter.)

Comment: By Euler's pentagonal-number theorem, the denominator $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)$ is $1 - q - q^2 + q^5 + q^7 - q^{12} - q^{15} + + - - \cdots$, so your sequence is $P(n-5) + P(n-7) - P(n-12) - P(n-15) + + - - \cdots$.  Beyond that I don't know.

Comment: Take a partition of n elements and remove 1 element from its smallest class. (If this gives an empty class, throw that away.) This gives P(n-1) results with (P(n)-P(n-1)) duplicates.  Maybe you are removing something like two elements? Gerhard "Trying To Add An Idea" Paseman, 2019.08.31.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Could you please elaborate a bit more or give an example? I didn't quite follow what you meant by smallest class.

Comment: There is a way of generating all partitions of N from all partitions of N-1, assuming they are presented as ordered tuples of positive integers: add 1 in at most two ways. If a partition of N-1 does not have a unique smallest member (say it starts 3,3,5, ...), then prepend a 1  (to make it 1,3,3,5, ,...), otherwise prepend and then for a new partition add 1 to the smallest number. I wonder if your process involves "adding 2". Gerhard "Just Trying To Brainstorm Here" Paseman, 2019.08.31.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Yes, the recursion process I am working with does involve adding 2. Actually, at a "level" $n$ I am solving for $P(n)$ unknowns and there are $P(n-1)$ linear equations from the next lower level and $P(n-2)$ linear equations from the next-to-next lower level.  The redundancies occur because the system gets over-constrained for $n\geq5$ .

Comment: I've added the sequence to the OEIS as [A324368](https://oeis.org/A324368).

Answer (score 3):

Let $C_k$ be the set of partitions of $n$ containing $k$.

Following @MaxAlekseyev's point we have,
$$P(n-1)+P(n-2)-P(n)=|C_1|+|C_2|-P(n),$$
$$=|C_1\cap C_2|+|C_1\cup C_2|-P(n)$$
This is the # of partitions containing both 1 and 2, minus the # of partitions containing neither 1 nor 2.

This number is nonnegative since to any partition containing neither 1 nor 2, writing it in nonincreasing order as $t_1,\dots, t_k$, we can associate the partition $t_1,\dots,t_k-3,2,1$ which does contain 1 and 2 (and this map is one-to-one).

Thus for all $n$, $P(n-1)+P(n-2)-P(n)$ is exactly counting

> how many partitions of $n$ contain both 1 and 2, and are not of the form $t_1,\dots,t_{k-1},t_k-3,2,1$ (removing $t_k-3$ if it is 0) where $t_1\ge\dots\ge t_k\ge 3$.

For $n=5$, this includes only one: $2+1+1+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented this on the computer and I seem to get the sequence 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 7, 10, **15, 21, 30, 41, 56, 76, 101,..** i.e. there is agreement till the 10. It is quite possible I am making a mistake though.

Comment: Here's the Mathematica code.
`add2[lst_] := 
  Table[lst + 2 IdentityMatrix[Length[lst]][[i]], {i, 1, Length[lst]}];
cBoole[f_] := 1 - Boole[f];
isSpecial[lst_] := 
  cBoole@MemberQ[cBoole@MemberQ[#, 1] & /@ add2[lst], 1];
isForm[lst_] := 
  If[EvenQ[Total[lst]] && Count[lst, 1] == 2 && 
    Count[lst, 2] == Length[lst] - 2, 0, 1];
which[n_] := (isForm[#] & /@ Partitions[n])*(isSpecial[#] & /@ 
     Partitions[n]);
bruteCount[n_] := Total[which[n]];
Table[bruteCount[n], {n, 1, 15}]`

Comment: @TheTwistedSector sorry I think I fixed it now

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $P(n-1)$ counts the number of partition of $n$ that contain $1$, while $P(n-2)$ counts the number of partition of $n$ that contain $2$.

It follows that $P(n-1)+P(n-2)-P(n)$ equals the difference between the number of partitions of $n$ that contain $\{1,2\}$ and the number of partitions of $n$ that contain neither $1$ nor $2$.